# What happens when you return View when should be PartialView?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In a View I am calling an action that returns a View

View:

```
 Html.RenderAction("Read", "Stats", new { Module = statsModel.Module, Name = statsModel.Name });
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Read(Module module, string name, bool showStatsItems = true)
    {
        eRPortalEntities db = new eRPortalEntities();
        StatsPanelService service = new StatsPanelService(db, UserID);
        StatsPanelViewModel spv = service.Read(module, name);
        spv.ShowStatsItems = showStatsItems;

        return View("StatsPanel", spv);
    }
```

This unfortunately causes some of my Bootstrap functionality to break. Such as dropdowns and modals not toggling.

If instead I have the controller return a PartialView, everything works as expected

```
return PartialView("StatsPanel", spv);
```

I'm not looking for a specific reason why my bootstrap stopped working but more of an explanation of... Why would this cause issues in general?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you explicitly specify the `Layout` to be null, When you do `return View("StatsPanel")`, Razor view engine will render the view content inside the Layout (_Layout.cshtml) similar to how you render a page normallly. That means, it will include all those scripts & Css in the head section again. That could be the reason it is messing up your markup.

Using `PartialView()` method seems appropriate in your use case. If you still want to use the `View()` method, you can explicitly define layout as null in your `StatsPanel.cshtml` view like this

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```